# How can I resolve a value when returning promise all?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am calling a promise function in a loop and I want to be able to return all of its promises and return a value (assetIds) as well. However I am after calling the function (addToCollectionMap) obj.assetIds is undefined.

```
function addToCollectionMap(client, json, collectionId) {
  var promises = [];
  var assetIds = [];
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      var list = JSON.parse(json)["list"];
      list.forEach(function (asset) {
          var assetId = asset["id"];
          assetIds.push(assetId);
          promises.push(setToCache(client, PREFIX + assetId, collectionId));
      });
      promises.push(resolve({assetIds: assetIds}));
  }).then(function () {
      return Promise.all(promises);
  });
}
```

Calling code:

```
   return addToCollectionMap(client, jsonString, collectionId)
        .then(function (obj) {
            return setToCache(client, ASSET_MAP_PREFIX + collectionId, obj.assetIds);
        });
```

Comment: I don't see any `obj` in the code you posted, which value do you mean?

Comment: @Bergi, I added the calling code. obj is supposed to be the result of addToCollectionMap

Comment: No it isn't, you used .then to instead make it equal to the results of all the promises.

Comment: @KevinB, I added a push, but even with that I am seeing result = undefined

Comment: you don't need the push, you simply need another .then that has a callback that returns the result you want on the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.then` is returning the promise created by `Promise.all(promises)`, therefore it will have the results of all the promises. You simply need another `.then` that returns what you want instead.

```
}).then(function () {
  return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(function () {
  return assetIds;
});
```